# What are the databases of semiconductor properties?

Tags: reference-request, one-topic-per-answer, databases, machine-learning, experimental

Is there any database listing the experimentally-determined properties of semiconductor materials - things like Band Gap and Electron Mobility. These are easily found for common materials like Germanium or Gallium Arsenide. But what databases have systematic lists properties for materials which are currently being researched (preferably by type, such as $\ce{ABX2}$).

These might prove very useful for computational studies (particularly Machine Learning approaches), as well as excellent references for characterization of synthesized materials.

Comment: It would be good for someone to ping Matt Horton since materials project serves some of these purposes.  I will avoid giving an answer until he can or its been a while, mainly since he can speak about it much better.

Comment: @TristanMaxson Its been quite a while and no one seems to have reached Matt (I for one have no idea how to). You could consider doing so your self or write an answer yourself?

Answer (score 6):

### Ioffe: New Semiconductor Materials. Biology systems. Characteristics and Properties

From the site:

> This section is intended to systematize parameters of semiconductor
> compounds and heterostructures based on them. Such a WWW-archive has a
> number of advantages: in particular, it enables physicists, both
> theoreticians and experimentalists, to rapidly retrieve the
> semiconducting material parameters they are interested in. In
> addition, physical parameters -optical, electrical, mechanical, etc.-
> will be presented in the framework of the electronic archive for both
> the known and new semiconducting compounds. As the starting point in
> creating the database served the voluminous reference book "Handbook
> Series on Semiconductor Parameters" vol. 1,2 edited by M. Levinstein,
> S. Rumyantsev and M. Shur, World Scientific, London, 1996, 1999. We
> express sincere gratitude to M.E. Levinstein for help and attention to
> this work. A great number of reference books and original papers cited
> at the end of this section have been used in compiling the information
> database.

Link: http://matprop.ru/

Comment: Thanks! This is certainly useful. But more focused on the most common semiconductors, so not exactly what I was hoping for.